# Как нарезать талоны на прием?

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать запрос.
Знаю время начальное и конечное время приема для каждого врача (например с 8:00:00 до 16:00:00), знаю длительность каждого приема в зависимости от специальности врача (0:20:00). Как запросом нарезать время на талоны?
т.е. примерно `ВРАЧ|8:00 - 8:20|8:20 - 8:40|...|15:40 - 16:00 |`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cbc4/5

Comment: А зачем это делать именно в SQL? Подобное проще и, по-моему, правильнее делать в коде приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть дикая идея: Заполнить таблицу временными отрезками (сутки каждого периода)

`| ID_специализации | Время начала | Время окончания |`

И делать запрос с объединением таблицы, в которой у вас врачи и временные ограничения и данной таблицы. Но мне кажется правильно вам подсказали в комментарии: лучше делать это вне базы.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что должно быть на выходе.
Чтобы разбить на сегменты, я бы использовал [курсор](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) и [хранимую процедуру](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Comment: На выходе нужна строка примерно такого вида. Если это, конечно, возможно